# IIS 8 - How can I redirect inactive websites

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

The situation I have is as follows:

There is Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8; in which there are many sites, for example user1.mysite.com, user2.mysite.com and so on.

If i turn off all (or some) of the websites, is there a way to redirect a part of these sites to another website, which would explain why the site is offline?

i.e. All sites are turned off:

- user1.mysite.com would redirect to siteX
- user2.mysite.com would redirect to siteY.

Answer (score 1):

Add a website that uses the IP(s) of these websites and add no host header for it. If a site using a certain IP binding is offline, this default site will be loaded instead. Then add a system to this site that will check the site that the user tried to access and give out whatever information you want.